# How would I concurrently update TOP N records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update some 25 records periodically. For this purpose, I have 5 jobs that execute a procedure at regular intervals. The procedure does something like this.

```
UPDATE
    TOP 5
    FooTable
SET
    col2 = 'taxi'
OUTPUT
    col1
WHERE
    col2 = 'uber'
```

If the 5 jobs called this stored procedure (SP), each SP would have locked the data for other SPs and the top 25 records would have been updated eventually.

Can the SP from 2nd job pick up the next TOP 5 rows with some locking granularities or hints, instead of waiting for the previous SP to complete?

Comment: why do you need a stored procedure for this ? you can get it done by running simple query. Any special reason ?

Comment: by doing what you asked may lead to Dirty Read

Comment: @UsmanRana I've quite oversimplified my original problem to this state. I'm in a situation where I'm to forced execute queries through SPs called from jobs running on multiple instances. I noticed that these `UPDATE` queries on TOP 5 records would be waiting for other `UPDATE` queries on previous TOP 5 records, which are definitely different. So I was thinking whether I could optimize the SPs to read and update next TOP 5 records directly, instead of waiting.

Comment: Why don't you try a ROWLOCK [hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table)?

Comment: Yes, it can - the `READPAST` hint is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;
GO 
CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ID INT,
    col2 INT
    );
INSERT #TestData (ID, col2)
SELECT 
    t.n, c.Col2
FROM
    dbo.tfn_Tally(200, 1) t
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10 + 1) ) c (Col2);

--=========================================================================================

-- before update values 
SELECT
    td.ID, td.col2,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY td.col2)
FROM
    #TestData td
WHERE
    td.col2 IN ( 3, 5 );

----------------------------------------------

WITH 
    cte_Top5 AS (
        SELECT TOP 5
            td.Col2
        FROM
            #TestData td
        WHERE 
            td.col2 = 5
        ORDER BY
            td.ID -- change this to determine which 5 are the top 5, or remove the ORDER BY all together if you don't care and save the sort expense.
        )
UPDATE t5 SET 
    t5.Col2 = 3
FROM 
    cte_Top5 t5;

----------------------------------------------

-- after update values 
SELECT
    td.ID, td.col2,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY td.col2)
FROM
    #TestData td
WHERE
    td.col2 IN ( 3, 5 );
```